# datepicker and focusout in textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a datepicker on a textbox and in the same time i'm using a function that checks if the user has entered the right date and time format using javascript.

The problem i am facing is that whenever i have the mouse selected on the textbox the datepicker shows as it should but if i want to select a date from the datepicker the focusout() function is executed and i must re-click again on the date from the datepicker to be selected.

here is my code:

```
     $('#StartDateTime').datepicker({
        /* here is only to stay focusin() on the textbox after selecting date */
        constrainInput: false,
        fixFocusIE: false,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            this.fixFocusIE = true;
            $(this).change().focus();
        },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            this.fixFocusIE = true;
            this.focus();
        },
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            var result = $.browser.msie ? !this.fixFocusIE : true;
            this.fixFocusIE = false;
            return result;
        }
    }).click(function () { $(this).focus() });

    $("#StartDateTime").focusout(function () {
        if (sDTValid() == false) {
            alert("Please enter Date (Day/Month/Year) & Time (HH:MM AM or PM)");
        }
    });

    function sDTValid() {
    /* this is the function of date and time format validation*/
        var sDT = document.getElementById('StartDateTime').value;
        if (sDT.match(/^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) (.*)$/)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: BTW Have you considered using http://jqueryvalidation.org/date-method/ it would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'focusout' event will be triggered when user click on the datepicker element because it's not part of the input#StartDateTime

you can use other event when value is changed eg. 'input'

```
$("#StartDateTime").on('input', function () {
    if (sDTValid() == false) {
        alert("Please enter Date (Day/Month/Year) & Time (HH:MM AM or PM)");
    }
});
```

Comment: It worked but now the date and time validation function is working only when a user tries to enter maunally the date and time and if the date is not valid and the user loses focus from the textbox the validation message is not showing !!! :S